# Python Pandas Error: "b'Skipping line X: expected X fields, saw X\ mysql workbench export

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm a beginner in sql dbms and python.

I've gathered 3 million tweets on MySQL workbench through Tweepy's Python library. Now I'd like to start running a sentiment analysis with the data I have. When I export it in literally every type of file (csv, json, SQL...) pandas shows this error :`"Error: Skipping line XXXX: expected XX fields, saw XX".`

I've looked into it and there's always an issue with the text field, with some tweets, there's a misread of certain characters (quotes most likely) that make pandas skip lines with almost half the database. Strings of data under text end up under the primary key field and so on.

I've tried making a connection directly to the server through `mysql.connector` but for some reason it gives me an error in that path as well.

I've read there's a way to avoid this type of issue with phpmyadmin but it would be better not to install a completely new DBMS and it seems quite unlikely this cannot be solved through MySQL workbench.

Thank you in advance for all the help you can give me!

Comment: "When I export it in literally every type of file (csv, json, SQL...)" Do you mean import? And with `read_csv()`, `read_json()`, etc.? For example, for `read_csv`, you can pass the `encoding` parameter and try different ones. Here is one article that discusses encoding: https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-pandas-read-csv-you-should-know-to-speed-up-your-data-analysis-1e16fe1039f3

Comment: @DavidErickson sorry for the incomprehension and thank you for the article you suggested. I mean: when I export the database in a csv format from mysql workbench for example and I load it into pandas, there's the error I described above. I thought it was a file type issue, so I tried exporting the file first in json, then SQL but the result wouldn't change. Even if I open it with excel, some lines are being skipped.